# how to create temp files on nfs-mounted NTFS

Tags: linux, permissions, ntfs, nfs

a linux server has nfs-mounted NTFS disk, there one can create regular files and folders. But there is an issue with temporary ones (permission denied) and therefore one can't (g)zip and make other operations requiring a temporary file (or dir). Is it possible to adjust system settings, so that temporary files can be created on the disk?

Comment: do you export /tmp ?

Comment: I do have TMPDIR set. It is local (not on the disk). Somehow it's not used when the temp files need to be created. The current dir seems to be used instead. How to make TMPDIR be used?